# ASP.Net: how to draw map

Tags: asp.net

HI,

I am assigned a task to develop module for an already existing web application or to look for some third party plugin.

The web application is developed using ASP.net and C# under .Net Framework 4.0. So if i develop by myself or i go for some 3rd party plugin then in both cases, my solutions need to work with above website specifications.

## What I am Assigned:

I need to draw a figure(or map) which illustrates that how companies registered on our website are connected with each other and then their sub companies, i am sorry i don't know how to explain it exactly :(, but following image would give a better idea what i want to achieve. I never do such task before, and only need guidance.

[image]

Image Taken From: http://www.visualcomplexity.com/vc/project_details.cfm?id=709&index=709&domain

Comment: IMHO this is almost like google maps with companies instead of places and connections instead of roads. I dont think you will get any third party plugin for this. this is super tough. also it would takes months to complete even with a great team. i am not being the pessimist here.but would like you to think all these before committing to this. is it not a lot better to lay out the difficulties to the person who gave this task and politely tell no? believe me, i had been in the exact circumstances where i was asked to do these kind of stuff :) btw its just my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are in for some fun :)

Infragistics seems to have a Silverlight control (http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/silverlight/data-visualization/organization-chart.aspx#Overview)

But you also might want to check out these as starting points:

http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart.html

http://www.kyleschouviller.com/wp-content/files/Vis.html

http://www.mindfusion.eu/features-netdiagram.html

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't wont to write graph code, better use some graph visualization library, look here for list :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44090/do-you-know-any-graph-visualization-libraries-for-net